# find best transformation matrix for two 2D data points

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scikit-image

how to find best transformation matrix for aligning two 2D point set   to get minimum Mean squared error value. this code is what I have done but this is not right: tform * src.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# estimate transformation parameters
src = np.array([0, 0, 10, 10]).reshape((2, 2))
dst = np.array([12, 14, 1, -20]).reshape((2, 2))
tform = tf.estimate_transform('similarity', src, dst)
print(src)
print(dst)
print(tform.params)
msq=mean_squared_error(tform*src,dst)
```

Comment: The correct invocation is `tform(src)`.  If you want the matrix behind the transformation, you have to access `tform.params`.

Comment: by print(tform.params) I got 3*3 matrix how can I use this matrix to multiply my 2d data?

Comment: `skimage.transform.warp(image, tform.inverse)` will modify an image, according to that transform.

Comment: thank you, but your answer does not clear for me since I am using 2D data and I dont know what do you mean by image ? and also if we want to use inverse of the src with src then I think they don't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I could find a right answer for my question

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# estimate transformation parameters
src = np.array([0,0 , 1,0 , 1,1 , 0,1]).reshape((4, 2))
dst = np.array([3,1 , 3,2 , 2,2 , 2,1]).reshape((4, 2))
tform = tf.estimate_transform('similarity', src, dst)
#tform is the transformation matrix for these data to align them
print(src)
print(dst)
print(tform.params)

mt = tf.matrix_transform(src, tform.params)#mt is the same dst
mean_squared_error(mt,dst) #should be zero
print( '{:.10f}'.format(mean_squared_error(mt,dst)) )
```